# Media volume control

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, volume

I'm developing adobe air application for mobile. I want to control android media volume like increase/decrease the media volume and mute/unmute the mediavolume. How can I control android media volume using adobe air.

Answer (score 0):

You should use native extension(ANE). This tutorial very helpful. 
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/building-ane-ios-android-pt1.html

Comment: I want to customize my app so I do't want to use android native extension(ane). I wish to use any thing useful without ane.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the volume, including muting, by using the SoundChannel and SoundTransform.

Example

```
var sound:Sound = new Sound("your.mp3");
var song:SoundChannel = sound.play();
song.soundTransform.volume = 0 // or any other volume between 0 and 1
```